# Fastest method to compare each character in string in a list of strings

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am working with an bioinformatic tool and constructed it using two loops to iterate over the each character.

The inputs (i.e. seq1 and sequence) are string of nucleotides such as '`AGATGCTAGTA'` of identical lengths. The `sequence_info` is a list of all of the sequences.

It was incredibly slow and so I increased the speed by using continue instead of adding zero and storing `bio_array` as a numpy array. Here's the new code.

```
for (sequence, sequence_location) in sequence_info:
    value = slow_function(seq1, sequence)

def slow_function(seq1,sequence):
    calc=0
    for i,nt in enumerate(seq1):
        if nt == sequence[i]:
            continue
        else:
            calc += bio_array[i]
    return float(calc)
```

Using `%%timeit` in jupyter notebooks it is still around a `100ms`. I would need it to be around or below `1-5ms`. I have tried transforming the function into an iterator and using list comprehensions/map instead of using loops. But these methods didn't have a significant affect.

I think that it might be possible to use numpy, but I haven't been able to find a method to use from looking at the documentation or on stackoverflow. As I need specific values from `bio_array` to be added together if there are mismatches in the sequence, I would need to compare each character value in the string individually I would think.

What would be the best way to increase the speed of this code to be as fast as possible?

Comment: Could you give some some example inputs and outputs to help everyone else understand the question better

Comment: @sshashank124, Thanks for letting me know, I added an example input.

Comment: Please provide some example data and turn your example into something that works and illustrates the actual problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - your example references several variables that are unspecified

Comment: why do you even return `calc`? you save it into `value` but with each loop `value` will be overridden and the calculated value is lost.

Comment: The result of `slow_function` appears to be the sum of those elements from `bio_array` that are in the same position as mismatching characters of `seq1` and `sequence` (which are supposedly of identical length)?

Comment: How large is your `sequence_info`? About how many data are we talking about? maybe you have to use parallel programming?

Comment: @Grismar, I didn't add any examples as there are preprocessing steps, but by using this code you can get an good aproximation `sequence_info = np.tile(['AAAAAAAAAAA', 100], (100000,1))
   seq1 = "AAAAAAAAAAA"`. Also you are correct, it is the sum of the `bio_array` where there are mismatching characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you wish to sum elements of an array based on where the two sequences of strings don't match. You can simply create characters array of your sequences and then use numpy conditional indexing to get the non-matching values. Here is a reduced example:

```
seq_a = np.array(list('ABCDEFGH'))
seq_b = np.array(list('ABCZEFZH'))
bio_array = np.array([1, 5, 9, 4, 3, 8, 2, 7])
```

Then, doing an element-wise comparison between `seq_a` and `seq_b` gives you:

```
>>> seq_a != seq_b
array([False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False])
```

You can then index `bio_array` with this result to get the relevant values and then sum them:

```
>>> bio_array[seq_a != seq_b]
array([4, 2])

>>> bio_array[seq_a != seq_b].sum()
6
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly the answer that I wanted. But unfortunately, the time used to convert the list into a np.array for each element in the list using list comprehensions would add too much time by increasing it to `170 ms`. Thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: Why not convert the whole thing to an array at once, and then you can even use numpy for the outer iteration instead of the `for` loops

Comment: That's what I did the first time, unfortunately. I think that my question is a bit insufficient to get a answer, and I would need to play around with parrellization as @Boendal recommended, or just bit the bullet and see if writing it in C will help.

Comment: As long as you avoid manual looping and stay in the numpy domain and use proper idiomatic numpy code, you should be able to get very good performance. I would first try to refactor the code to avoid these manual `for` loops as much as possible, before trying more drastic changes such as rewriting it in another language

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remove all of the manual for-loops and use proper numpy code to see how best to increase speed.

Answer (score 2):

You should accept @sshashank124's answer, but here's a quick bit of code to show what is going on and how much it differs:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit


def slow_function(seq1, seq2, costs):
    calc = 0
    for i, nt in enumerate(seq1):
        if nt == seq2[i]:
            continue
        else:
            calc += costs[i]
    return float(calc)


def shorter_slow_function(seq1, seq2, costs):
    return sum(costs[i] for i in range(len(seq1)) if seq1[i] != seq2[i])


def faster_numpy_function(seq1, seq2, costs):
    return costs[seq1 != seq2].sum()


x = np.array(list('ABCDE'))
y = np.array(list('XBCDY'))
c = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])


print(timeit(lambda: slow_function(x, y, c)))
print(timeit(lambda: shorter_slow_function(x, y, c)))
print(timeit(lambda: faster_numpy_function(x, y, c)))
```

Results:

```
6.7421024
6.665790399999999
5.321171700000001
```

Comment: Note that the value of `shorter_slow_function` lies in not relying on numpy - in this particular simple example, just using Python lists and that function would be faster than converting everything to numpy arrays and using `faster_numpy_function`.

Comment: Thanks for the time breakdown. It was really helpful. I'll change my code to be like the `shorter_slow_function`. Like you mentioned it was slower to convert everything to numpy than to just use a different method.